# Passing $scope reference working but i'm not fully understand why

Tags: angularjs

I'm populating a $scope array by exetrnal functions which counts from `min` to `max` . 
I am passing the array to the function (without passing the $scope), and adding values to the reference of the passed array. The values are successfully added to the $scope array but i'm not sure why is this working. Can anyone clarify?

Here is the code:

**In controller**

```
$scope.Minutes = [];
numbersToScopearray(0, 60, $scope.Minutes);
```

**Outside the controller**

```
function numbersToScopearray(min, max, scope) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        if (i < 10) { value = "0" + i; } else { value = i; }
        scope.push({ 'value': value, 'display': value });
    }
}
```

The values that i add to `scope` are also added to `$scope.Minutes` . Which is good, but why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the object $scope.Minutes and you give it as an argument to the function. So when you do something to 'scope' which is '$scope.Minutes' it modifies the array pointed by both in memory. 
Do you need more explanations ?